# how to use form data in Alamofire

Tags: swift, form-data

In the postman in the body section in the form-data part when I pass a mobile number as a key and mobile number as Int value I get a response. But when I did it in the code I will not get the response as expected.

my code is

```
 func fetchRegisterData(){

          let url = registerApi
     
    var mobileNumber = mobilenumberTextfield.text
    
    let parameters = ["mobile" : mobileNumber] as [String : Any]
    
     AF.request(url,method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding:JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON
              { response in switch response.result {
              case .success(let JSON):
                  print("response is :\(response)")
            
              case .failure(_):
                  print("fail")
                  }
          }
          
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to pass parameters as `multipart/form-data` you have to use the upload method in `Alamofire`:

```
func fetchRegisterData() {
    let parameters = ["mobile": mobilenumberTextfield.text!]

    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multiFormData) in
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multiFormData.append(Data(value.utf8), withName: key)
        }
    }, to: registerApi).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let JSON):
            print("response is :\(response)")

        case .failure(_):
            print("fail")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**For normal Alamofire request -**

While passing values as a parameter in Alamofire Request. You need to know about the data type of the request type values which is valid for API.

At API end, these values are getting parsed based on some data types. There must be some validations on the data type at the API side.

for mobileNumber, it can be either **Int or String**

```
1 - let parameters = ["mobile" : mobileNumber] as [String : Int]
2 - let parameters = ["mobile" : mobileNumber] as [String : String]
```

**For multipart form data request** use have to use something like below. However, if you are not uploading anything you should not use it. Ask API team to make changes in the API and normal parameters request

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: {  (multipartFormData) in
    
    //Try this
    multipartFormData.append(mobileNumber, withName: "mobile")
    //or this
    multipartFormData.append("\(String(describing: mobileNumber))".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "mobile")

}, usingThreshold: 10 * 1024 * 1024, to: apiUrl, method: .post, headers: [:], encodingCompletion: { (encodingResult) in

    switch encodingResult {
                
            case .success(let upload, _, _):

            case .failure( _): 
                
            }
})
```